# How to overwrite API Route names?

Tags: c#, api, rest, routes, url-routing

I have my Route name in the controller as below:

```
 [Route("api/v1/[controller]/[action]")]
    [ApiController]
```

Is it possible to change in the config level to overwrite the above Route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using .net core and mvc, you can add global config like this in your startup config method.

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
   routes.MapRoute("default",  "myApi/v1/{controller=values}/{action=get}/{id?}");
});
```

Comment: I am using .Net core and i want to change the route values in config level. Is it possible to change? Because the code is already built and i want to change the route values in the appsettings.config level

Comment: Yes this is possible but after this change, you should rebuild your project. If you can't rebuild project, you should think about redirection from you web server.

Comment: Now i added the routes in the global.asax and now i am able to access. Thanks for the support.